# Find duplicate data sql server 2008 (case sensitive)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to find duplicate data in  database

my query is like this

```
SELECT  ID, FK1,FK2,FK3 , COUNT( * ) as duplicate   
FROM Pilkada.dbo.Transaction    
Group by ID, FK1,FK2,FK3    
having COUNT(*) >1
```

The data return like this

[image: 1]

But when I select query where data is duplicate the Result:

[image: 2]

The question is **how to find duplicate data on sql server with case sensitive**.

so the query can distinguish it really duplicate or not.

Thank you

> Sorry my senior just playing trick with me the data he just show is on
>   Linked Server and  is true the server is care sensitive
>   Please mark this Question is close.

Comment: I guess, you want case insensitivity according to your images instead of case sensitivity, right?

Comment: I wanted to find duplicate data using query above. but the result said that i have duplicate data. but when i select data using ID, PK1, PK2, PK3. the result on PK1 is different because care sensitive on server.

Comment: sql server is case insensitive by default. that's why you've found this type of situation

Answer (score 3):

Use collations. In example below I used Polish collation, but you can use another.

CI = Case Insensitive, AI = Accent Inensitive, CS = Case Sensitive, AS = Accent Sensitive

```
SELECT
    ID,
    FK1 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI,
    FK2 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI,
    FK3 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI,
    COUNT(*) as duplicate
FROM Pilkada.dbo.Transaction    
GROUP BY
    ID,
    FK1 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI,
    FK2 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI,
    FK3 COLLATE Polish_CI_AI 
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Sort of example

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
    k1 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('Mars')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('mars')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('maRs')
INSERT INTO #t VALUES ('MARS')

SELECT *
FROM #t
WHERE k1 = 'mars'

SELECT k1 COLLATE Polish_CS_AS , COUNT(*)
FROM #t
GROUP BY
    k1 COLLATE Polish_CS_AS

SELECT k1 COLLATE Polish_CI_AS , COUNT(*)
FROM #t
GROUP BY
    k1 COLLATE Polish_CI_AS

DROP TABLE #t
```